# Content-Disposition: download file automatically

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js, filesaver.js

The API call to the server is returning a zip file with `Content-Disposition` in format `attachment, <filename>`
I am using FileSaver's saveAs to save the file.

```
    this.ajax.raw(requestUrl, {
        dataType: 'binary',
        xhr: () => {
          const myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr()
          myXhr.responseType = 'blob'
          return myXhr
        }
      }).then((response) => {
        this.downloadSuccess(response, minTimeString, maxTimeString, downloadCompletedMessage)
      }).catch((e) => {
        this.downloadError(e)
      })

downloadSuccess (response, minTime, maxTime, downloadCompletedMessage) {
    const filename = (response.jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition').split('"')[1])
    saveAs(response.payload, filename, 'application/zip')
```

This works fine for small files but fails if the file is more than 2Gb (The file is downloaded successfully but the saved file is of 1Kb only).

During my research, I saw that browser can download the file without FileSaver if the response has `Content-Disposition` which is true in my case. But I am not able to figure out how.

Do I need to use request differently?

Comment: is there any reason why you dont just call `window.open`?

Comment: Agreed with this or the single answer that has been posted. Your failure likely has to do with memory issues in your JS app, so you’ll probably have better success if you let the browser and server sort things out without your app being in the middle. That said, it will mean your UI has to change as you can no longer track what is going on as easily. But if that matters you could setup an alternate tracking setup on the server side of things and have your Ember app poll for download status instead

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/wiki/Saving-a-remote-file#using-http-header):

> Content-Disposition attachment header is the best preferred way to
> download files from the browser. It has better cross browser
> compatibility, won't have any memory limit and it doesn't require any
> JavaScript.

You don't need `ajax request` to download the file. Only ensure that server add `Content-Disposition` header and provide a link to download.

If you can also use the anchor [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) from HTML5.

> Causes the browser to treat the linked URL as a download.

```js
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = '/xyz/abc.pdf';
link.download = "file.pdf";
link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
```

```html
<a href="/xyz/abc.pdf" download="file.pdf"></a>
```

Comment: does `requestUrl` goes in link.href?

Comment: Because the code fails with Network error.

Comment: yes, `requestUrl` becomes the `link.href` and `link.download` is the filename as the file will be saved.